# C# Compress and zip csv from stream

Tags: c#, .net, csv, zip, mailmessage

I have a MemoryStream which pulls data from a DataTable. Currently this feeds into a MailMessage Attachment and mails out a csv attached to the mail. What I need to do is to compress and zip it.

So right now I am iterating through each row of a DataTable, adding appropriate commas, and streaming it out. It results in a .bin file with the data. By adding a name as an Attachment argument it sends to the client as a valid csv file.

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "report.csv"));
```

Can anyone help as to how I could compress and zip the csv before adding it as an attachment? Preferably without external libraries. Thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files

Comment: Pass the stream directly to a zip file stream and then pass that stream to the attachment

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi GZipStream seems to be the class to compress the stream. How do I ensure that when the end user unzips it that they receive either a csv or Excel file?

Answer (score 6):

For a previous answer, with a model like this,

```
public FileModel(){
    public string FileName {get;set;}
    public Stream FileStream {get;set;}
}
```

The following extension methods were defined to create a zip archive to stream.

```
public static class ZipArchiveExtensions {    
    public static Stream Compress(this IEnumerable<FileModel> files) {
        if (files.Any()) {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            using(var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true)) {
                foreach (var file in files) {
                    var entry = archive.add(file);
                }
            }
            ms.Position = 0;
            return ms;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static ZipArchiveEntry add(this ZipArchive archive, FileModel file) {
        var entry = archive.CreateEntry(file.FileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
        using (var stream = entry.Open()) {
            file.FileStream.CopyTo(stream);
        }
        return entry;
    }
}
```

With that you can now add a step before adding the compressed csv file(s) as attachments

```
//...other code

var files = new FileModel[] {
    new FileModel {
        FileName = "report1.csv",
        FileStream = stream
    },
    new FileModel {
        FileName = "report2.xlsx",
        FileStream = stream2
    }
};

var zipStream = files.Compress();
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(zipStream, "reports.zip"));

//...other code
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm getting this error attempting to use this solution on .net core 2.2: ```Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in System.IO.Compression.dll: 'This stream from ZipArchiveEntry does not support seeking.'```. This happens on the ```stream.Position = 0;```

Comment: @WiniciusIago in that case then remove the line with the position and close. The `using` block will dispose of the stream. This works fine on previous version of .net. Something might have changed in the newer versions.

Comment: Thanks @Nikosi. it seemed to work but the attached zip file seems to be invalid(despite being 2,3mb, which is the size I expected). I'm getting this error trying to open the zip file on linux ```Failed to open archive: Not a zip archive```

Comment: @WiniciusIago Ok provide some background about what you are doing so we can see if we can try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to do almost the same thing as the author of the question. I have a big csv that I need to send by email, the file must be compressed otherwise it might hit the max limit of the smtp server. Maybe the only difference is that I'm generating the csv in memory based on a database query. The final csv is a string which I then convert to a Stream and pass it to the extensions on your answer

Comment: @WiniciusIago hmmm, Ok, Alright, Post a new question with the relevant parts, including how the stream is passed to the archive.

Comment: Thanks @Nikosi, just created the question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414669/compress-and-zip-file-from-string>

Comment: @WiniciusIago was away for a bit. Now seeing your link. Did you not see the update made where the archive was being disposed.