# Dynamically create zip MemoryStream from multiple downloaded files

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an endpoint for a web app that downloads multiple files from an external server, creates a zip file, and passes the zip to the client on the front end.

I want to know if its possible to do the entire operation as a MemoryStream as opposed to downloading the files, writing them to the disk, sending the file to the front end, and finally deleting all associated files.

Ideally, I dont want any R/W operations, and don't need to preserve any of the files

Currently, my code looks like this

```
public FileResult DownloadMulti([FromBody] List<DownloadInfo> requests)
{
// declare download location, zip/directory names, etc. 

// create directory
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                
// download the video files from given links 
foreach(DownloadInfo request in requests)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            // download the file to tempDir
            String filename = directoryName + "\\"+foo+".mp4";
            client.DownloadFile(request.DownloadUrl, filename);
        }
    }

// Create Zip File
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(directoryName, zipName);

// delete the dir recursively 
System.IO.Directory.Delete(directoryName, true);

// return + delete zip
var fs = new FileStream(zipName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);

fs.Position = 0;

return  File(
        fileStream: fs,
        contentType: System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet,
        fileDownloadName: zipName);

}
```

Most related solutions I've found deal with creating the zip file in a MemoryStream from files already present on the server, but none (that I could find) deal with files that need to be downloaded to the server first. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably using [`WebClient.OpenRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.openread?view=net-5.0) and other parts of the ZipFile API.

Comment: See if this gives you any ideas https://stackoverflow.com/a/44485099/5233410